# Access Messages from Message Center

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hi I’m try to display the top 5 messages from the message center on the homepage. But I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong. I try to get the messages from the message view model here is my code.

View model

```
@model Portal.ViewModel.MemberMessageViewModel

@foreach (var msg in Model.MessageList)

<div> @html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.CreatedOn) @html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.Subject) </div>
```

MessageViewModel.cs

```
public class MemberMessageViewModel : BaseViewModel { public string Subject { get; set; } public string CreatedOn { get; set}

   public List<MemberMessageViewModel> MessageList { get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> 

Homepage()
{
  string MESSAGE_PANEL_NAME = _configuration.GetSection(“TemplateStrings”).GetSection(“TEMPLATE_MESSAGECENTER”).Value;

try{
 memberHomepageVM.messageDetail = await _messageService.GetHomepageMessages(MESSAGE_PANEL_NAME, Lang);
}
```

Cshtml

```
@awaitHtml.PartialAsync(“_message”, Model.messageDetail)
```

Comment: Should I use ViewBag instead of model ViewBag MessageList in the foreach?

Comment: What's the relationship between the memberHomepageVM.messageDetail and the MemberMessageViewModel? According to your code and description, I suppose in the Homepage controller, you want to get the top 5 MemberMessageViewModel  messages from the _messageService, and then display it on the Homepage view page, right? If that is the case, when you query data from the _messageService, you could use the `OrderByDescending()` to sort the message based on one column and then use the `Take(5)` method to get the top 5 messages, then, return it to the view page and display the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display top 5 records, we should use the "[OrderByDescending()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1)" to sort the message, and then use the "[Take(5)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1)" method to get the top 5 messages.

Please refer the following sample code:

1. Based on your MemberMessageViewModel create a service, and set initial data:

   ```
      public class MessageService : IMessageService
        {   
           public List<MemberMessageViewModel> GetHomepageMessages()
            {
                List<MemberMessageViewModel> messagelist = new List<MemberMessageViewModel>()
                {
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S1", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S2", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6).ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S3", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4).ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S4", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S5", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S6", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8).ToString()},
                    new MemberMessageViewModel(){ Subject="S7", CreatedOn=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString()},
                };

                return messagelist;
            }
        }
   ```
2. Register the service in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

   ```
      services.AddScoped<IMessageService, MessageService>();
   ```
3. Homepage controller:

   ```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Homepage()
    {
        //get the message list
        var messages = _messageService.GetHomepageMessages()
            .OrderByDescending(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c.CreatedOn))   //sort the message based on the CreatedOn property.
            .Take(5)  //take the top 5 messages.
            .ToList();

        //according to your view page bind model, it seems that you want to return a MemberMessageViewModel.
        MemberMessageViewModel member = new MemberMessageViewModel()
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            Subject = "Subject A",
            MessageList = messages,
        };
        //
        return View(member);
    }
   ```
4. Homepage view page(Homepage.cshtml):

   ```
        @model Test.Models.MemberMessageViewModel

        @foreach (var msg in Model.MessageList)
        { 
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.CreatedOn)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.Subject)
            </div><br/>
        }
   ```

The output as below:

[image]

Besides, you could also sort and take the messages from the View page:

```
        @model Test.Models.MemberMessageViewModel

        @foreach (var msg in Model.MessageList.OrderByDescending(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c.CreatedOn)).Take(5))
        { 
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.CreatedOn)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => msg.Subject)
            </div><br/>
        }
```

If I misunderstand your problem, please let me know freely.